# How to judge exactly the same in the child table

Tags: sql, oracle

In my Oracle DB, I have 2 tables `d` and `w`:

`table d`

```
    INVOICECODE    VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)     PRIMARY KEY  
    COMBINATIONNAME    NVARCHAR2(100 CHAR)  
    STARTTIME    DATE  
    ENDTIME    DATE  
    STATUS    NUMBER(10,0)  
    .....
```

`table w`

```
SERIALID  VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)  PRIMARY KEY  
INVOICECODE  VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)  
WARECODE  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)  
WARENAME  NVARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
```

....

When I add or edit data on the WEB UI, I must to verify that `STATUS` time does not overlap and  sub-table data can not be exactly the same.

e.g. the new data is

```
StartTime: 2017/07/25  
EndTime: 2017/07/28  


WareCode   WareName  
123        A   
222        B
```

if there are two rows date in the `w` table(WareCode: 123，222) ，meet the conditions, can't add the new data;
if WareCode: 123  or WareCode: 123，222, 456， can add the new data. how to write the sql:

```
select count(1) from d 
where status = 1 
and (StartTime BETWEEN '2017-07-25' AND '2017-07-28' 
     OR EndTime BETWEEN '2017-07-25' AND '2017-07-28' 
     OR '2017-07-25' Between StartTime AND EndTime 
     OR '2017-07-28' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime) 
and (/*....*/)
```

the sample data
table d  :

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| INVOICECODE | COMBINATIONNAME   | STARTTIME        | ENDTIME          |  STATUS  | 
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1101        | GoodsCombination1 | 2017-07-10 00:01 | 2017-07-20 15:00 |  0       |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1105        | GoodsCombination2 | 2017-07-24 15:00 | 2017-07-26 15:00 |  1       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 210         | GoodsCombination3 | 2017-07-26 12:00 | 2017-07-27 15:00 |  1       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 88          | GoodsCombination4 |  017-07-25 09:00 | 2017-07-26 09:00 |  1       |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The STATUS column can be 0, 1, 2(Not audited、Audited、Rejected)
table w uses INVOICECODE association table d

table w  :

```
|----------------------------------------------|
| SERIALID | INVOICECODE | WARECODE | WARENAME |
|----------------------------------------------|
| 1        |   1101      |   123    |  A       |
|----------------------------------------------|
| 2        |   1105      |   123    |  A       |
-----------------------------------------------|
| 3        |   1105      |   222    |  B       |
-----------------------------------------------|
| 4        |   1105      |   300    |  D       |
-----------------------------------------------|
| 5        |   210       |   123    |  A       |
-----------------------------------------------|
| 6        |   210       |   222    |  B       |
-----------------------------------------------|
| 7        |   88        |   123    |  A       |
-----------------------------------------------|
| 8        |   88        |   300    |  D       |
------------------------------------------------
```

When new data like this, can insert to db:

```
CombinationName: aaaaa  
StartTime: 2017-07-20 00:00:00  
EndTime: 2017-07-23 00:00:00  

WareCode   WareName  
222        B   
300        D
```

Like this, can't insert db because 210' status=1 and there are two identical data in table d:

```
CombinationName: aaaaa  
StartTime: 2017-07-20 00:00:00  
EndTime: 2017-07-23 00:00:00  

WareCode   WareName    
123        A     
222        B
```

Can't insert db because status=1 and time overlap of 1105, 210, 88 in table d:

```
CombinationName: aaaaa  
StartTime: 2017-07-25 00:00:00  
EndTime: 2017-07-27 00:00:00  

WareCode   WareName  
123        A   
222        B 
44         F
```

---

Maybe sort the new data for WareCode, and then use the below SQL :

```
Select Count(1) From (
  Select (
      Select
           listagg(WareCode, ';') within group (Order by WareCode) as mergeWareCode
    From w
    Where InvoiceCode = d.InvoiceCode
    Group by InvoiceCode
  ) as mergeWareCode, d.InvoiceCode From d
  Where d.Status = 1 and ( StartTime Between to_date('2017-07-25','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('2017-07-28','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
    or EndTime Between to_date('2017-07-25','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('2017-07-28','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
    or to_date('2017-07-25','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') Between StartTime and EndTime
    or to_date('2017-07-28','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') Between StartTime and EndTime ) 
) Where mergeWareCode='123;222'
;
```

Comment: Please spend some time explaining your use case. So 'w' is the parent and 'd' is the child? 'd' is a history of `status` values for a given  `invoicecode`? You want to valid the datetime ranges before inserting a record into `d`? At the very least please expand the sample data so it presents complete records, with starting states and end states for successful and rejected transactions.

Comment: So 'w' is the parent and 'd' is the child?  ----  yes,  The relation like order and products of order